# Pytest never completes the Flask route test. But when it gets killed in the cmd the tests run and pass

Tags: python, flask, pytest

Ok, i am positively stomped at the moment. I try to set up a very generic unit test to test the route for the Flask API. Except the test never ends, it spins up the Flask server and then just hangs there for ever.

But when i go to the cmd and crtl+c kill the task, it runs the test and they pass.. But if i never ctrl+c the test never end (or never even start).

What seems to be the issue with Flask and Pytest that makes it so that the Flask server get spun, and then just does nothing until i try to force it to close ?

The code i am trying to test is this:

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import load_model
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np
import joblib

app = Flask(__name__)

# load the model
model = load_model('LSTM-KarelOfzo.h5')
scaler = joblib.load('scaler2.pkl')


@app.route('/Glucose/<date>')
def get_glucose_data(date):
    df_glucose = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
    # Where 'Tijdstempel apparaat' contains date value, drop all NaN rows that are present in 'Snelwerkende'
    df_fast_insuline = df_glucose[df_glucose["Tijdstempel"].str.contains(date)]
    df_fast_insuline = df_fast_insuline.dropna(subset='FastInsulineUnit')

    # Where 'Tijdstempel apparaat' contains date value, drop all NaN rows that are present in 'Historisch'
    df_historic_gluc = df_glucose[df_glucose["Tijdstempel"].str.contains(date)]
    df_historic_gluc = df_historic_gluc.dropna(subset='historicGluc')
    
    # Where 'Tijdstempel apparaat' contains date value, drop all NaN rows that are present in 'Scanned'
    df_scanned_gluc = df_glucose[df_glucose["Tijdstempel"].str.contains(date)]
    df_scanned_gluc = df_scanned_gluc.dropna(subset='scannedGlucose')

    # Where 'Tijdstempel apparaat' contains date value, drop all NaN rows that are present in 'Koolhydraten'
    df_carbs = df_glucose[df_glucose["Tijdstempel"].str.contains(date)]
    df_carbs = df_carbs.dropna(subset='carbs')

    # Set all indexes of dataframes to 'tijdstempel'
    df_fast_insuline = df_fast_insuline.set_index('Tijdstempel')
    df_carbs = df_carbs.set_index('Tijdstempel')
    df_historic_gluc = df_historic_gluc.set_index('Tijdstempel')
    df_scanned_gluc = df_scanned_gluc.set_index('Tijdstempel')
    #combine all dataframes to one where timestamp is == to timestamp already present in df4
    df_historic_gluc = df_historic_gluc.combine_first(df_carbs)
    df_historic_gluc = df_historic_gluc.combine_first(df_fast_insuline)
    df_historic_gluc = df_historic_gluc.combine_first(df_scanned_gluc)
    
    df_historic_gluc.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df_historic_gluc['Tijdstempel'] = pd.to_datetime(df_historic_gluc['Tijdstempel'].str.replace('_', ' ')).dt.strftime('%H:%M')

    df_historic_gluc.set_index('Tijdstempel', inplace=True)
    #index and record data objects to Array of JSON objects
    df_historic_gluc = df_historic_gluc.reset_index()

    return df_historic_gluc.to_json(orient='records')

@app.route('/prediction/<insuline>/<carbs>/<glucose>')
def test_get_prediction(insuline, carbs, glucose):
    
    # Define input data for prediction
    data = np.array([[insuline, carbs, glucose]])
    # Normalize the input data
    data_norm = scaler.transform(data)

    # Reshape the input data for the LSTM model
    n_features = data_norm.shape[1]
    timesteps = 1
    data_norm = np.reshape(data_norm, (data_norm.shape[0], timesteps, n_features))

    # Make the prediction for the next 15 minutes
    predicted_glucose_15min = model.predict(data_norm)

    return str(predicted_glucose_15min[0][0])
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False)
```

pyUnitTests.py :

```
from Flask import app
import time

class TestFlaskAPI(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = app.test_client()

    def test_get_glucose_data(self):
        response = self.app.get('/Glucose/1-5-2023')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.content_type, 'text/html; charset=utf-8')

    def test_get_prediction(self):
        response = self.app.get('/prediction/10/50/100')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.content_type, 'text/html; charset=utf-8')

    def tearDown(self):
        # Wait for 1 second before closing the app
        time.sleep(1)
        self.app.testing = False
        self.app = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The output of the test :

````py
========================================================================================================== test session starts ===========================================================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.0, pytest-7.3.1, pluggy-1.0.0 -- C:\Users\....\Python\Python39\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: C:\Users\....\Python
collecting ... 2023-05-10 00:48:46.723249: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
 * Serving Flask app 'Flask'
 * Debug mode: off
collected 2 items  <---- HERE it hangs until i kil it with crtl+c

//Only after that it finaly runs a test.
pyUintTests.py::TestFlaskAPI::test_get_glucose_data PASSED
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 238ms/step
PASSED

============================================================================================================ warnings summary ============================================================================================================ 
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:246
  C:\Users\..\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:246: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool8` is a deprecated alias for `np.bool_`.  (Deprecated NumPy 1.24)
    np.bool8: (False, True),

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
====================================================================================================== 2 passed, 1 warning in 8.52s ====================================================================================================== ```
````

Answer (score 1):

So your app is stored in `Flask.py` and you want to run tests in `pyUnitTests.py`.

The problem in your code is the last line of `Flask.py`:

```py
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False)
```

Imports actually run the module you wanna import.
And as the `app.run` is not guarded by an `if __name__ == '__main__'`, It will spin up the app when importing it for the tests. That's why you need to press `Ctrl+c`, to stop the currently running flask app and then your tests run.

So just use

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False)
```

and your tests should run.